# Facing this java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle length is not aligned by 4: 9 in Model class which implements Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, illegalstateexception

```
public class Profile implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("profileName")
private String profileName;
@SerializedName("paused")
private boolean isPaused;
@SerializedName("numberOfDevices")
private int numberOfDevices;

private boolean isSelected;

public Profile(String profileName, Boolean isPaused, int 
numberOfDevices) {
    this.profileName = profileName;
    this.isPaused = isPaused;
    this.numberOfDevices = numberOfDevices;
}

protected Profile(Parcel in) {
    profileName = in.readString();
    isPaused = (boolean) 
in.readValue(boolean.class.getClassLoader());
    isSelected = (boolean) 
in.readValue(boolean.class.getClassLoader());
    numberOfDevices = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<Profile> CREATOR = new Creator<Profile> 
.() {
    @Override
    public Profile createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Profile(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Profile[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Profile[size];
    }
};

public String getProfileName() {
    return profileName;
}

public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
    this.profileName = profileName;
}

public Boolean getPaused() {
    return isPaused;
}

public void setPaused(Boolean paused) {
    isPaused = paused;
}

public int getNumberOfDevices() {
    return numberOfDevices;
}

public void setNumberOfDevices(int numberOfDevices) {
    this.numberOfDevices = numberOfDevices;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}



@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(profileName);
    dest.writeValue(isPaused);
    dest.writeInt(numberOfDevices);
    dest.writeValue(isSelected);
}
```

}

> I would like to pass the profile object through intents so I created the model class which implements Parcelable. This is my Model class which implements Parcelable. My model class
>   contains two boolean fields where I am having an issue with "isSelect"
>   field and not with "isPaused" field. Don't know the reason for this. I
>   searched online but didn't get any solution for this. The crash logs I
>   see is as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle length is not aligned by 4: 9
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3447)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2146)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bundle length is not aligned by 4: 9
        at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1615)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.<init>(BaseBundle.java:143)
        at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:95)
        at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:2301)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2946)
        at com.centurylink.ctl_droid_wrap.models.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:34)
        at com.centurylink.ctl_droid_wrap.models.Profile$1.createFromParcel(Profile.java:41)
        at com.centurylink.ctl_droid_wrap.models.Profile$1.createFromParcel(Profile.java:38)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2990)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2883)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3261)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:951)
```

Comment: please share complete code for this class

Comment: @greeble31 I updated the details.

Comment: Instead of using Boolean class loader try storing as an integer 0 or 1 and convert back to Boolean on construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected Profile(Parcel in) {
    profileName = in.readString();
    isPaused = in.readByte() != 0;
    numberOfDevices = in.readInt();
    isSelected = in.readByte() != 0;
}
```

If I replace this code with existing Profile(Parcel in) it works fine